# Selenium+Java Encontrar el xpath correcto

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Cómo están?

Estoy usando Selenium con Java y necesito hacer clic en una opción. El elemento es un radiobuttom.

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked="">
                            30 días (TNA 24.50%)  (14/05/2018)
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="0" checked="" data-hj-masked="">
                            <div class="radiobutton-indicator" data-hj-masked=""></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked="">
                            60 días (TNA 25.50%)  (12/06/2018)
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="1" data-hj-masked="">
                            <div class="radiobutton-indicator" data-hj-masked=""></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked="">
                            90 días (TNA 25.50%)  (12/07/2018)
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="2" data-hj-masked="">
                            <div class="radiobutton-indicator" data-hj-masked=""></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked="">
                            180 días (TNA 26.50%)  (10/10/2018)
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="3" data-hj-masked="">
                            <div class="radiobutton-indicator" data-hj-masked=""></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

El problema es que, cuando inspecciono el elemento en la opción a clickear, me resalta *label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked*, y esto es exactamente igual en las 4 opciones.
Lo que las diferencia es el atributo "value" que es 0,1,2 y 3 respectivamente.

Alguna ayuda para armar el xpath seleccionando una de las opciones?

Como referencia, el xpath absoluto que me copia el inspector es:
/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/label/div

Desde ya, muchas gracias!!

Edit:

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Plazo_Fijo {

    WebDriver driver;
    String urlprueba;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        urlprueba = "https://asdasd/login";
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void PlazoFijoTradicional() throws InterruptedException {
        // Login
        driver.get(urlprueba);
        //Ingreso credenciales
        driver.findElement(By.id("DocumentNumber")).sendKeys("11111111");
        driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("usuario");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
        //Ingreso al menú y funcionalidad
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Inversiones")).click();
        WebElement NuevaInv = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#buttons-container > button"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='box']/h3[normalize-space()='Plazo Fijo']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btn-submit\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ImporteVisible")).sendKeys("2000");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btn-submit\"]")).click();
        //Aquí el problema -->
        List<WebElement> resultados = driver.findElements(By.name("radio"));
        resultados.get(0).click();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido para enteder mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour].

Comment: No podrias agregarle una clase o un id al radio button?

Answer (score 1):

Bien, luego de googlear e investigar un poco encontré el motivo por el cuál no podía encontrar el elemento. 
Firefox me tiraba este error:
 *org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (589.7833251953125,343.5) because another element  obscures it*

El tag `<label>` se está superponiendo al tag `<input>`

Finalmente con:

```
//input[@value='3']//parent::label
```

funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias a todos por el feedback.

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
// Obtiene todos los elementos con el nombre radio
List<WebElement> resultados = driver.findElements(By.name("radio"));

// Obtiene el primer elemento y lo clickea
resultados.get(0).click();
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Por algún motivo, no puedo usar esa función para obtener todos los elementos: "List cannot be resolved to a type". Como quick fixes me da la posibilidad de importar 'List' (java awt) y 'List' (java.util). Pero con ninguna funciona. Busqué información sobre List<WebElement> y la sintaxis que acercaste es correcta, no sé que puede estar mal.

Comment: Tiene que ser un problema de **import**. Puede actualizar tu respuesta y agregar el código que tienes hasta ahora, incluyendo los imports.

Comment: No me deja por cantidad de caracteres. Los imports:  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

Comment: Me refiero a que lo agregues a tu pregunta

Comment: Hecho, gracias!

Comment: Pude utilizar "List<WebElement>" correctamente. Efectivamente faltaba un import. Pero no funcionó: "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="3" data-hj-masked=""> is not clickable at point (594, 342). Other element would receive the click: <label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked="">...</label>"

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a Stackoverflow:

Para eso puedes usar el siguiente comando que te muestro, por poner un ejemplo:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("radio")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='radio'])[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='radio'])[3]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='radio'])[4]")).click();
```

El primero hará click en el primer radio button, el segundo en el segundo y así sucesivamente. De esta forma podrás simular el click en un radio button concreto.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. No funcionó, me retorna el error que otros elementos pueden ser clickeables: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="2" data-hj-masked=""> is not clickable at point (1699, 278). Other element would receive the click: <label class="control radiobutton" data-hj-masked="">...</label>

Answer (score 0):

Puedes construir un xPath del estilo:

```
//input[@id='radio' and @value='0']
```

Para que seleccione el combo que quieres, de los 4 radioButton los 'value' van del 0 al 3, en este caso seleccionaria el primer radioButton, en el caso que quieras seleccionar otro, deberás cambiar el valor del value por el radioButton al que corresponda.

Saludos,